# Rails sort element by click a button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

Scenario: there is a sort button, when user click it, the list will sort by `name`(it sort by `created_at` before).

I got a problem is that, I did sort code in ruby, but how do I know when user click the button?

For example:

```
<button id = "sort_btn">Sort by name!</button>
...

<%# before_sort is origin array %>  
<% sort_arr = Array.new(before_sort) %>
<%# x[1] is the name attribute %>
<% sort_arr.sort_by!{|x| x[1]} %> 
<%# if click sort button %> 
<% sort_arr.each do |section_layer1| %>
<%# if did't click sort button or click twice sort button %>
<% before_sort.each do |section_layer1|>
    <%= render :partial => 'list', :locals => {:section => section_layer1 }%>
<% end %>
```

I thought that I might use Javascript to delete origin display and render partial view again after user click sort button.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript! You can add a get parameter manually on click:

```
$(".sort_btn").on('click',function(){
  if (url.indexOf('?') > -1){
  url += "&sort=sort";
  }else{
  url += "?sort=sort";
  }
  }

  window.location.href = url;

  });
```

And then, if the parameter exists, print the sorted table:

```
<%- if params[:sort].present? %>
  -- print sorted table --
<%- else %>
  -- not sorted --
<% end %>
```

Comment: Finally, I choose to use `link_to + remote true` and then render `respond_to js.erb`.